# How to modify JPEG compression in PDF files using ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'd like to reduce PDF file size not only by reducing image DPI but also by changing quality settings of JPEG compression.

First I tried:

```
gs  -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen \
-dColorImageResolution=120 -dGrayImageResolution=120 \
-dUseFlateCompression=false -sOutputFile=test1.pdf \
-c "<< /GrayImageDict << /Blend 1 /VSamples [1 1 1 1] /QFactor 0.1 /HSamples [1 1 1 1] >> /ColorImageDict << /Blend 1 /VSamples [1 1 1 1] /QFactor 0.1 /HSamples [1 1 1 1] >> >> setdistillerparams " \
-f test.ps
```

Second I changed Gray- / ColorImageDict entries and tried:

```
gs  -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen \
-dColorImageResolution=120 -dGrayImageResolution=120 \
-dUseFlateCompression=false -sOutputFile=test2.pdf \
-c "<< /GrayImageDict << /Blend 1 /VSamples [2 1 1 2] /QFactor 2.4 /HSamples [2 1 1 2] >> /ColorImageDict << /Blend 1 /VSamples [2 1 1 2] /QFactor 2.4 /HSamples [2 1 1 2] >> >> setdistillerparams " \
-f test.ps
```

But the result of both commands are identical in size.

Any suggestions what's the mistake / misunderstanding or how to increase JPEG compression otherwise?

(Version: GPL Ghostscript 9.16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to share an example file and command liens so that others can reproduce your findings. Without that, its not possible to say why you are getting the results you are.

Your command line isn't ideal. You've used one of the canned PDFSETTINGS, I wouldn't do that if I were you. Use the defaults and alter the ones you want to change. You've mixed command line switches and a PostScript call to setdistillerparams. It would be better to use just setdistillerparams.

The most likely reason is that you aren't getting JPEG in the output, note that you haven't disabled auto filter selection. As described in the distiller params documentation, UseFlateCompression only affects the page compression, not images, and in any event is fixed to true (see the Ghostscript documentation) in Ghostscript. Setting it to false does nothing.

So I'd suggest you post a sample file and we take it from there.

Oh and you should use the current version, 9.16 is 2 years old.

Comment: Key hint was "auto filter selection". So either adding `/AutoFilterColorImage false` or changing `/ColorImageDict` to `/ColorACSImageDict` makes the command working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for posting that, I was puzzled as to what I'd said that helped :-)